# Error while running ORB_SLAM as a ROS node

Tags: ros, slam-algorithm

Following the tutorial provided in this [link,](https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2) I am trying to run ORB_SLAM as a ROS node in ROS Indigo. After executing the line /.build_ros.sh, I am facing a list of errors,

```
/home/ubuntu_16/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/../../../Thirdparty/g2o/g2o/types/../core/jacobian_workspace.h:30:22: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/RGBD.dir/build.make:118: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/RGBD.dir/src/ros_rgbd.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/RGBD.dir/src/ros_rgbd.cc.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/RGBD.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/RGBD.dir/all] Error 2
```

I am unable to get rid of these problem, if someone has faced the same, please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you install Eigen? Try this:

`sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev`

Comment: Please check that have the file in `/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core`.